# Pinax Structure

Tags: python, pinax

I have just installed the Pinax but i'm very confused now.

in my structre

i have two directories

mysite and mysite-env

I dont why i have two directories. I  just followed the installitation directions

in mysite,

```
<project-root>
    apps/
        __init__.py
    deploy/
        __init__.py
        fcgi.py
        wsgi.py
    fixtures/
        initial_data.json
    locale/
        ...
    requirements/
        base.txt
        project.txt
    sitemedia/static // I move static file from mysite-env to here
        ...
    templates/
        _footer.html
        homepage.html
        site_base.html
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

However,

default index page is in `mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/banner_base.html`

Should i manage my site from mysite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pinax uses virtualenv](http://pinax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#installation) to prevent messing up your local python libs by your project dependency.

So, launch the site with `$ source mysite-env/bin/activate` it will be fine. If you really hate `mysite-env`, just [skip](http://pinax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#creating-a-project) the virtualenv part.

Comment: is it possible to run pinax without virtualenv

Comment: Absolutely possible, install Pinax in your system python environment and just skip the `$ source mysite-env/bin/activate` .